# Upper and lower case indices in matrix notation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, index-notation

In my matrix algebra book, *Matrix Algebra Useful For Statistics* by S. Searle and A. Khuri, I came across several equations that include upper and lower case indices for rows and columns. This dichotomy confuses me, and I have not seen this kind of notation anywhere else except in this book. Unfortunately, there is no explanation for this notation. What reason is there to distinguish between lower and upper case letters?

Here is an example of an equation for differentiating determinants of symmetric matrices that uses this notation:

> $$\dfrac{\partial|\boldsymbol{X}|}{\partial x_{IJ}} = |\boldsymbol{X}_{iJ}| + |\boldsymbol{X}_{IJ}| - \delta_{ij}|\boldsymbol{X}_{Ij}| \quad \text{for symmetric } \boldsymbol{X}$$

where $|\boldsymbol{X}_{ij}|$ is a minor, i.e. the determinant of $|\boldsymbol{X}|$ with its $i$th row and $j$th column removed.

**Update:** Another example, which uses this notation, is the definition of the determinant expansion by minors (expansion by rows)

> $$|\boldsymbol{A}| = \sum_{J=1}^n a_{ij}(-1)^{I+j}|\boldsymbol{M}_{ij}| \quad \text{for any } i$$

which clearly shows that all $i$'s, whether lower or upper case, are identical. Another point that bothers me here is that the index of the summation is an upper case $J$, even though all the column indices in the equation are lower case.

At first, I thought it might be because the authors wanted to emphasize the index of the expansion, but that cannot be the case since it is not done consistently. Especially considering that the same definition when expanding the elements of the column of some matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is,

> $$|\boldsymbol{A}| = \sum_{I=1}^n a_{IJ}(-1)^{I+j}|\boldsymbol{M}_{Ij}| \quad \text{for any } j$$

Even though it is not a very crucial question, I still wonder what the meaning of this notation might be, since I do not see its relevance.

Comment: Perhaps there's an implied sum over lower-case indices, or something, but it's hard to tell without more details about what is shown here.  Is $x_{IJ}$ the $I$-$J$'th element of $X$, or is it a coordinate, and the matrix elements of $X$ are functions of $x_{ij}$? In $|X_{IJ}|$, is $|\cdot|$ meant to be an absolute value or a determinant, and correspondingly, is $X_{IJ}$ a matrix or the $I$-$J$'th element of $X$?  I suppose that $|X|$ means determinant, and $|X_{IJ}|$ means the absolute value of the $I$-$J$'th element of $X$, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Another option is that the $|X_{iJ}|$ means something like the determinant of $X$ with some rows and columns removed.  Can you please clarify?

Comment: After trying a few examples, I suspect that all of the indices should be the same (either all $i$ and $j$ or all $I$ and $J$), that $X_{ij}$ means $x$ with row $i$ and column $j$ removed, and that $|\cdot|$ means determinant throughout.

Comment: Thank you for your input, I included some additional information. And about your second comment: Indeed, $|\boldsymbol{X}_{ij}|$ represents a determinant of $\boldsymbol{X}$ whose $i$th row and $j$th column have been deleted.